# Getting @EJB in the context

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, stateful-session-bean

as discussed here [Display username in jsp redirected from a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966076/display-username-in-jsp-redirected-from-a-servlet) to get the same instance of a Stateful Session Bean, i have to save it in the HttpSession related. It is working good, but in a servlet i did so:

```
SessionCart cart = (SessionCart) request.getSession().getAttribute("cart");
if (cart==null){
   cart = new SessionCart();}
```

Where the attribute "cart" is the one where i saved the initialized cart. The problem is that, if the cart was not initialized before, the row cart=new SessionCart(); initialize a bean not related to Context, so the entitymanager got by @PercistenceContext is null. I tried to use the annotation

```
@EJB
private SessionCart cart;
```

but this one create a new session cart anyway, without my control (so if i have a cart related to user yet, i create a new one and i trash it... this is not so good). My question is: could i create a new Stateful Session Bean without using annotation @EJB and getting it related to context? So i can control when i want to create it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it correct, you want to initialize your bean lazy.

To control/create your bean at runtime you could use `Instance<Bean>` [Java EE API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html)

In your case it would look like that:

```
@Inject
private Instance<SessionCart> sessionCartInstance;

if (cart == null) {
    cart = sessionCartInstance.get();
}
```

Comment: i found even the way ses = (SessionCart) new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/ibei/ejb/SessionCart"); what do you think is better? It's the first time i see Instance<T> class

Comment: This is a manual lookup, if you don't use remote EJBs I would prefer Instance as it is type safe.

Comment: Thx, great explaination, finally i found a great way to do it!